# angularjs additional form validation rules (not input field validation)

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

What's the angular way to add validation rules to a form, that do **not** belong to a single input field, but on multiple field values together?

E.g.:

- Check if at least one of x checkboxes is checked
- Check if the sum of multiple number inputs is equal to a given Number
- ...

It would be nice if the errors can be shown with ng-messages. I'm using angular 1.3.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality, but it requires little effort.

`ng-messages` does not depend on anything specific. It just needs an object whose keys can be referenced by `ng-message`. The simplest solution would be to hook into the `submit` event (which you probably do anyway) and run additional validation.

```
<form ng-submit="post()" name="myForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="one" ng-model="one" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="two" ng-model="two" />
  <input type="submit" />
  <div ng-messages="formErrors">
    <p ng-message="tooMany">Please, check one checkbox only</p>
    <p ng-message="required">Please, check a checkbox</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

On submission the function `post()` is called which adds any error to the object `formErrors`:

```
$scope.post = function() {
  ...
  var hasErrors = false;
  $scope.formErrors = {
  };

  if ($scope.one && $scope.two) {
    $scope.formErrors.tooMany = hasErrors = true;
  }

  if (!$scope.one && !$scope.two) {
    $scope.formErrors.required hasErrors = true;
  }

  if (hasErrors) {
     return;
  }
}
```